# Get custom object T in list List<T> based on key

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a list of what I call `Actions` that looks like this

```
public class Actions
{
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Observations { get; set; }

        public Actions(
            string type,
            string observations)
        {
            Type = type;
            observations= type;
        }
}
```

That I later on use in a List like `List<Actions> data= new List<Actions>();`

This list will hold types of birds, and the times they where observed. This data comes from a file that I read one by one. So being inside a loop, I will might find `Eagle, 1` and this means that I have to find inside that list the object that has `type==Eagle` and add +1 to its `observations` key.

I can iterate over this list of course and check if its `i`th object's `type` key, has the value that I want and increment it's `observations`.

Does anyone know a better way of doing what I am after?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I can iterate over this list of course and check if its ith object's type key, has the value that I want and increment it's observations.

Yes, that'll work.

You'd do it like this:

```
var birdToUpdate = birdList.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Type == keyToFind);
if (birdToUpdate == null)
{
    birdToUpdate = new Actions(keyToFind, 0);
    birdList.Add(birdToUpdate);
}
birdToUpdate.Observations++;
```

If none is returned, it's the first observation for that bird, so you add it.

Then later, if you want to add color into the mix:

```
var birdToUpdate = birdList.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Type == keyToFind 
                                             && b.Color == colorToFind);
if (birdToUpdate == null)
{
    birdToUpdate = new Actions(keyToFind, colorToFind, 0);
    birdList.Add(birdToUpdate);
}
birdToUpdate.Observations++;
```

---

An alternative would be to dump this class entirey and introduce a `Dictionary<string, int>` in which the key is the bird's name and the int the number of observations.

Or, if you insist on using this class, then please think of a proper name for the class and make it a `Dictionary<string, Actions>`.

Pseudo:

```
Actions actionForBird;

if (!dictionary.TryGetValue(keyToFind, out actionForBird))
{
    actionForBird = new Actions(keyToFind, 0);
    dictionary[keyToFind] = actionForBird;
}

actionForBird.Observations++;
```

Comment: In fact At first I had the exact thing you are suggesting, using a dictionary for my data. But unfortunately I cannot change it into a dictionary because it is only now that I only have to worry about observations, pretty soon I will probably have to worry about colors, location, etc. So I had to dump the dictionary, and subsequently cant use `TryGetValue` anymore.

Comment: What if I use multiple dictionaries, one for each possible key (eg Observations) just until I form my data and then when every variable is ready in its own Dictionary, I can combine them in my final object?

Comment: I have a difficulty in seeing how `FirstOrDefault()` can solve my issue here?

Comment: Could you incorporate this comment to your answer? I believe it might have value for anyone stumbling upon this.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a lambda expression using Dictionary

example

```
var type = 'eagle';
Dictionary<string, int> observations = new Dictionary<string, int>();
var obj = observations.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Key == type);
```

put the user input into `var type`

Comment: Why use a dictionary if you're going to iterate over all keys anyway (`FirstOrDefault`)?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible to change the data type right now.

Comment: The whole point of using a dictionary is that it holds a hashmap which makes retrieving a value by key an O(1) operation. You're iterating the dictionary sequentially, which could potentially be an O(n) (at worse).